# How to read JSON data from URL into XPage Java Bean

Tags: java, xpages

I get that typically this is something better done with Client Side JavaScript. However CSJS is not ideal in this situation for other reasons.

BUT if I have a Java object inside XPages.  A managed bean maybe or whatever.  Is it possible to read in JSON information to the object for parsing purposes?  In theory I'd want to process the data and use it in a TypeAhead for an editbox control.

The reason I'm interested in this rather then using the more tradition domino object model is the speed of getting the entries.  I'm wondering if a view thats using the great "startkey" parameter is faster then something like getAllEntriesByKey().

For instance this view:
http://xpagescheatsheet.com/fakenames.nsf/1fcbbeb633d9fdb3852576480057a7dc?ReadViewEntries&outputformat=JSON&StartKey=Fav

To to sum up I'm look to see if it's possible to injest the data from that link into a Java Object from XPages.  the key could be anything...  doesn't have to be "Fav".

Thank you!

Comment: Apache HTTP client is your friend. I got something similiar running but it's not apprently public.Drop me a note to gain you access to my repo

Comment: I've done something similar a couple ways, either by shoving it into a *Scope'd var (turning it into an object Object) _or_ by reflecting it via GSON into a Java Object. About ingesting the JSON output from a ?ReadViewEntries, I generally avoid that entirely as it's such a goofy structure. It _can_ be done, but there's a lot of overhead for what could be more easily done via another mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 parts to the question:

1. How to read data from an URL. Here Oliver provided the hint: use the Apache HTTP client (the libraries are in XPages)
2. How to turn that JSON into a Java object. Here I would use [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) and a matching object. The Apache HTTP client gives you access to an input stream for the body. Something like

   `SomeClass createFromJson(InputStream in) {
           Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
           SomeClass sc = gson.fromJson(in, SomeClass.class);
           return sc;
     }`

Comment: ... and then wrap GSON into a plugin and then you're rocking :-)

Answer (score 3):

I definitely support the way Stefan suggests - and I do that myself.

If you wrap Gson in a plugin you need to take care of security and permissions. I have just recently written an [article about exactly](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/elevating-permissions-for-your-third-party-jar/) this (with Gson as the example)

However, if you do not want to add extra libraries to your application then you can also use the built-in JSON functionality (in package: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json) to obtain the same - though not in the same elegant way.

Here is a small example:

```
JsonJavaFactory factory = JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx;
Object jsonObjs;
try {
    String url = "http://.....";
    jsonObjs = JsonParser.fromJson(factory, new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream())));
    for (Iterator<Object> val = factory.iterateArrayValues(jsonObjs); val.hasNext();) {
        JsonJavaObject obj = (JsonJavaObject) val.next();
        Double idNum = (Double) obj.getJsonProperty("id");
        String id = Integer.toString(idNum.intValue());
        if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(id)) {
            String name = (String) obj.getJsonProperty("name");
            // Do something with id and name...
        }
    }
} catch (JsonException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

/John

Comment: But... if you want to deal with _real_ Java objects, reflection with GSON is pretty amazing. 

Comment: I totally AGREE - and that is what I do all the time. But I know that David mentioned an issue about not being able to use "non-standard" code (the OpenNTF Domino API) the other day.... - so just wanted to show the alternative as well ;-)